# R: Getting mean value per season per year

Tags: r

I’m pretty new to R (I have used it a couple of years ago, and know a bit of the basics). For my thesis I have a lot of data that needs to be analyzed. I need to get the mean value per season, per year. So for example the mean value for the months 3,4,5 (spring) for every year. I have tried to google what to do but can’t really find what I’m looking for. Is there someone who can help me?

This is what I’ve tried so far:

```
#  Convert to date if not already
df1$Date = as.Date(df1$Date)

#  Get months
df1$Month = months(df1$Date)

#  Get years
df1$Year = format(df1$Date,format="%y")
```

But it doesn’t add the column Month, and the outcome from df1$Year also isn’t right (see below):

```
Location    Date        N       Year    
1       8-1-2015      0,38      8-1-2015
1       2-2-2015      0,8       2-2-2015
Etc.
```

And this is a part of one of the data files:

| Location | Date | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8-1-2015 | 0,38 |
| 1 | 2-2-2015 | 0,8 |
| 1 | 2-3-2015 | 0,42 |
| 1 | 2-4-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 5-5-2015 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 18-5-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 2-6-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 15-6-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 29-6-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 6-7-2015 | 0,09 |
| 1 | 13-7-2015 | 0,09 |
| 1 | 27-7-2015 | 0,08 |
| 1 | 3-8-2015 | 0,09 |
| 1 | 10-8-2015 | 0,09 |
| 1 | 24-8-2015 | 0,09 |
| 1 | 7-9-2015 | 0,07 |
| 1 | 6-10-2015 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 2-11-2015 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 7-12-2015 | 0,36 |
| 1 | 11-1-2016 | 0,59 |
| 1 | 9-2-2016 | 0,77 |
| 1 | 14-3-2016 | 0,57 |
| 1 | 11-4-2016 | 0,11 |
| 1 | 9-5-2016 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 9-6-2016 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 20-6-2016 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 4-7-2016 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 18-7-2016 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 1-8-2016 | 0,06 |
| 1 | 9-8-2016 | 0,08 |
| 1 | 15-8-2016 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 29-8-2016 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 12-9-2016 | 0,05 |
| 1 | 3-10-2016 | 0,11 |
| 1 | 14-11-2016 | 0,28 |
| 1 | 13-12-2016 | 0,39 |

Comment: You can use `strftime(df1$Date, "%m")` for the month and `strftime(df1$Date, "%Y")` for the year.

Comment: `as.Date` hopes for `YYYY-MM-DD` format by default. Since you don't start in that format, you'll need to specify the format or use a different function. Since you are using `lubridate`, I'd recommend `df1$Date = dmy(df1$Date)` as the first line. Make sure that works correctly before proceeding. Then you can use `df1$Month = month(df1$Date)` and `df1$Year = year(df1$Date)`. **Note there is no `s` in this `month()` function.** `month()` extracts the month from a date. `months()` with an `s` is a different function, that converts to a duration.